# Alternate descriptions of finite fields

Tags: finite-fields, fields, computer-algebra, alternative-proof

The finite field of order $p^n$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z)[X]/(P)$, where $P$ is an irreducible polynomial in $(\mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z)[X]$ of degree $n$. This describes every finite field up to isomorphism.

My question is, what are alternate ways of describing these finite fields?

For example, Conway gave an alternate way of describing the fields $GF(2^{2^n})$ (see [this example answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/302374/65915)).

Comment: Try $A/\mathfrak m$ for $A$ any finitely generated $\mathbf Z$-algebra and $\mathfrak m$ a maximal ideal in $A$.

Comment: @KConrad, as suggested perhaps by the username, it seems that @‍PyRulez might be searching for a computationally effective presentation.

Comment: Maybe you can define a multiplication on $\Bbb F_p^2$ via $ (x,y)(x',y') = (xx'-yy', xy' + x'y)$ and this might give you a field isomorphic to $\Bbb F_{p^2}$.

Comment: @Watson, of course "maybe" [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/302373/alternate-descriptions-of-finite-fields/302374#comment753931_302373) means "if and only if $p \equiv -1 \pmod4$" (i.e., if and only if $-1$ is not a square already in $\mathbb F_p$).

Comment: @LSpice : yes, obviously. I just wanted the OP to have a thought about it.

Comment: I added the 'alternative-proof' tag since it can be viewed this way (alternative constructive proof of the existence and maybe uniqueness up to isomorphism, of a field of cardinal $p^n$), and 'computer-algebra', which can be a motivation for such a question (since implementing a field of order $p^n$ can be done in various ways).

Answer (score 2):

In [ONAG chapter 6](https://books.google.com/books?id=tXiVo8qA5PQC&q=the%20curious%20field#v=snippet&q=%22we%20abolish%22&f=false), Conway gives a way of defining the finite field $2^{2^n}$ for any natural $n$. The domain is $\{0,1,\dots, 2^{2^n}-1\}$. Addition is defined by the two rules:

1. The sum of $2^x$ and $2^y$ with $x \ne y$ is just the regular $2^n+2^m$. (So $13 = 8 + 4 + 1$.)
2. The sum of two equal numbers is $0$.

Multiplication is likewise defined by two rules.

1. The product of $2^{2^x}$ and $2^{2^y}$ with $x \ne y$ is just their ordinary product.
2. The square of $2^{2^x}$ is the ordinary product of $\frac 32$ and $2^{2^x}$.

This uniquely defines the field. For example, using only the field axioms and above rules, we conclude $$5 \times 9 = (4+1)(4\times2+1) =\\ 4^2 \times 2 + 4 \times 2 + 4 + 1 = 6 \times 2 + 8 + 4 + 1 =\\ (4 + 2) \times 2 + 13 = 4 \times 2 + 2^2 + 13 =\\8 + 3 + 13 = 6$$

Also see this [addition](http://www.neverendingbooks.org/DATA2/nimaddition.jpg) and [multiplication](http://www.neverendingbooks.org/DATA2/nimmultiplication.jpg) table.

Conway goes on to extend this to the set $\{\alpha:\alpha < \beta\}$ for certain ordinals $\beta$, and to the class of all ordinals to create the curious Field $\text{On}_2$.

One nice thing about this construction is it shows show $GF(2^{2^n})$ is isomorphic to a subfield of $GF(2^{2^m})$ for any $n \le m$.

Comment: It seems a bit strange to post a question and an answer simultaneously.  Rather, it probably makes more sense to make this part of the question itself, so that people can see what kind of answer you want (which wasn't clear to me from the question, at least).

Comment: @LSpice I edited the question to link to this answer. I thought the answer was a little big to include in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's only a tiny bit different, but if you put $\omega=\exp(2\pi i/(p^n-1))$ and $A=\mathbb{Z}[\omega]<\mathbb{C}$ then $A/pA$ is a product of fields, each of order $p^n$ (and therefore isomorphic to each other).